# Save and Load Custom Dictionary - NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have an `[Int:Bool]` dictionary and I am trying to save it into my NSDictionary.. However, it crashes with error `Attempt to set a non-property-list object`

```
let dictionary = [Int:Bool]()


self.dictionary[2] = true
self.dictionary[3] = false

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dictionary, forKey: "dictionary")
```

---

Also, for loading, first I tried this but error logged it strictly requires AnyObject?.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("dictionary")
```

Then I tried this and it logged:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("dictionary") as? [Int:Bool]
```

I also tried `dictionaryForKey`. I got..

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("dictionary")
```

> Cannot assign value to type [String: AnyObject] to type [Int:Bool]

---

So which one of these 2 is a better approach to take? (The values would be optional in my case I think)

```
1.
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("dictionary") as? [Int:Bool] ?? [Int:Bool]()

2.
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("dictionary") as? [Int:Bool])!
```

Comment: Have you synchronized your NSUserDefaults after saving? `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()`

Comment: I think you should use `dictionaryForKey(_:)`.

Comment: Ahh. I totally forgot to add it to the question. I also tried it.. Getting an error.. Updated my question

Comment: Why do you access `dictionary` with `self.` if you declare it in the current scope?

Comment: Also, you obviously can't add values to a dictionary that you declared with `let`...

Comment: I want to use it in other pages too (and after re-opening the app). I tried using: `let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.dictionary)` `self.defaults.setObject(data, forKey:"key")` but couldn't understand what to do while loading.. :/

Comment: @senty You still can't modify a dictionary declared with `let`, and unless the code you provided isn't in the same scope, `self.dictionary` won't access a dictionary you just declared.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Swift 4

Among basic types, `UserDefaults` can save any object that conforms to `Codable` protocol. `Dictionary` is one of the types that implements this protocol. You don't even need to write any custom code:

```
let dictionary = ["name": "Adam"]

// Save to User Defaults
UserDefaults.standard.set(dictionary, forKey: "names") 

// Read from User Defaults     
let saved = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "names") as? [String: String]
```

See more info about [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable)

## Swift 3

You can use `UserDefaults` to save a `Dictionary` as long as key and value types are types that can be represented in a plist format (`NSNumber`, `Data`, etc.). If that's not the case, we can always serialise other types to `Data` when writing and deserialise from `Data` when reading. It can be accomplished with pretty simple extension of `UserDefaults` using `NSKeyArchiver`:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    /// Save dictionary on key
    open func set<Key, Value>(dictionary: [Key: Value]?, forKey key: String) {
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dictionary as Any)
        set(data, forKey: key)
    }

    // Retrieve dictionary for key
    open func dictionary<Key, Value>(forKey key: String) -> [Key: Value]? {
        guard let data = object(forKey: key) as? Data else { return nil }
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Key: Value]
    }
}
```

Now you can call these methods:

```
let ages = ["Adam": 25]

// Save
UserDefaults.standard.set(dictionary: ages, forKey: "ages")

// Read
let saved: [String: Int]? = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "ages")
print(saved) // Optional(["Adam": 25])
```

## Swift 2

*Save custom data*

```
func setCustomDictionary(dict: [Int: Bool]) {
    let keyedArch = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dict)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(keyedArch, forKey: "dictionary")
}
```

*Retrieve data*

```
func getDictionary() -> [Int: Bool]? {
    let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("dict")
    let object = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data as! NSData)
    return object as? [Int: Bool]
}
```

*Usage*

```
var customDictionary = [Int: Bool]()
customDictionary[2] = true
customDictionary[3] = false

// Store data in NSUserDefaults
setCustomDictionary(customDictionary)

// Get data from NSUserDefaults
let userDefaultsDictionary = getDictionary()
```

Comment: Isn't something of type `[Int: Bool]` automatically casted to an `NSDictionary`?

Comment: No. It's because Swift dictionary is generic structure `Dictionary<T,E>` while `NSDictionary` is ObjectiveC `NSObject` derived class. They were bridged in earlier versions of Swift, but they are not now.

Comment: Can you back that up with a source? This works for me in a playground: `let dictionary: NSDictionary = [1: "a", 2: "b"]`.

Comment: @TimVermeulen it seems that `NSDictionary` is still bridged with swift `Dictionary`. Conversion between types does not happen automatically and you can initialize `NSDictionary` with swift dictionary syntax.

Comment: But this also works: `let dict = [1: "a", 2: "b"]; let nsDict: NSDictionary = dict`

Comment: I am getting an error `replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver` on the NSArchiver in the save function

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but with different types of data.
My suggestion is to convert to NSData and retrieve the data like so:

```
/// Save
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(object), forKey: key)

/// Read
var data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) as NSData
var object = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as [String: String]
```

(Although it is mentioned [String : String] I actually used for [[String: AnyObject]] and worked, so maybe it can work for you too!)

Answer (score 0):

This is for Swift 3

```
func setCustomDictionary(dict: [Int: Bool]) {
    let keyedArch = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dict)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(keyedArch, forKey: "dictionary")
}

func getDictionary() -> [Int: Bool]? {
    let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "dict")
    let object = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: (data as! NSData) as Data)
    return object as? [Int: Bool]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you neeed more types you can use generics like this:

```
func saveUserDefaults<T>(withKey key: String, dict: AnyObject, myType: T.Type) {
    guard let dict = dict as? T else {
        print("Type mismatch")
        return
    }
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dict)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(archiver, forKey: key)
}

func getUserDefaults<T>(withKey key: String, myType: T.Type) -> T? {
    let unarchivedObject = getUserDefaultData(withKey: key)
    return unarchivedObject as? T
}

func getUserDefaultData(withKey key: String) -> Any? {
    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let retrievedData = data as? Data else {
        return nil
    }
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: retrievedData)
}
```

For example [Int:Int] type usage:

```
    var customDictionary = [Int: Int]()
    customDictionary[234] = 1
    customDictionary[24] = 2
    customDictionary[345] = 3

    saveUserDefaults(withKey: "hello", dict: customDictionary as AnyObject, myType: [Int: Int].self)
    let savedDictionary = getUserDefaults(withKey: "hello", myType: [Int: Int].self)
    print(savedDictionary)
```